# MySQL: Two Records to One Record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have one table like this.

```
id conversation_id messageable_id
 1               1              3 <--
 2               1              5
 3               2              7
 4               2              3 <--
 5               3              7
 6               3              9
```

One conversation has two member.

If sender is 3, I have to get all conversation and receiver like following.

```
 conversation_id sender_id recevicer_id [sic]
               1         3            5
               2         3            7
```

How can I build query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lead()` (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select *
from (
    select
        conversation_id,
        messageable_id sender_id,
        lead(messageable_id) over(partition by conversation_id order by id) receiver_id
    from mytable
) t
where sender_id = 3
```